# SSH and LDAP auth with groups

Tags: ssh, openldap, pam-ldap

I have SSH/LDAP working just fine with public keys and all on an AWS Linux instance.  I'm using nss-pam-ldapd and pam_ldap.
But when I set /etc/pam_ldap.conf as follows to restrict login to a LDAP group:

```
pam_groupdn cn=Administrators,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com
pam_member_attribute memberUid
```

The LDAP user is then not allowed to log in.  Local accounts can log in just fine and LDAP accounts can log in if the pam_groupdn line is commented out.

The only logged item is from sshd:
Access denied by PAM account configuration.

Here are the pertinent lines from /etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so
```

Does anyone have any insight into what is happening here?

Comment: Just use 'AllowGroups' parameter in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Comment: Hi Danila.  Thanks for that.  I was pretty focused on the pam_ldap config.  Commenting out pam_groupdn and setting AllowGroups in sshd_config did the trick.  Behaviour is as expected and this has the advantage of being able to use multiple groups.

Comment: One thing if you're reading this for a solution - ensure that in addition to the LDAP groups in AllowGroups, that you also include any local groups (such as wheel) for local accounts.  I use local accounts for admins with proper sudo permissions in addition to LDAP accounts.  This in case LDAP falls down.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to use pam_ldap i would advise you to use pam_filter instead of pam_group_dn. What does your /etc/pam.d/system-auth look like?

Comment: The account excerpts are included above.  I tried a number of variations with pam_ldap.so - to no avail.  I think I like the ssh AllowGroups approach though.  It's reasonably scalable, well documented and easy to troubleshoot.  So far, nothing about LDAP has been simple, but once it works - it's great.